# Shortest path via two intermediate points

Tags: python, graph, pathfinding

My code takes a long time for big graphs.

How can I make it faster?

I'm trying to calculate the shortest path for 3 path's using queue but for big input my program crashes.

I'm stuck here. Can someone help me?

```
def bfs(graph, start, end):
    queue = []
    queue.append([start])
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        if node == end:
            return len(path)
        for adjacent in graph.get(node, []):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(adjacent)
            queue.append(new_path)

def all_possiblities():
    possiblites = []
    for clinique in cliniques[0][1:]:
        for clinique2 in cliniques[1][1:]:
            path1 = bfs(sorted_connections, a, clinique)
            path2 = bfs(sorted_connections, clinique, clinique2)
            path3 = bfs(sorted_connections, clinique2, b)
            total_path = path1 + path2 + path3
            possiblites.append(total_path)
    return min(possiblites) - 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_values = input().split()
    n, m = int(input_values[0]), int(input_values[1])
    a, b = int(input_values[2]), int(input_values[3])
    connections = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(m)]
    cliniques = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(m, m+2)]
    sorted_connections = {}
    for road in connections:
        city1, city2 = road
        sorted_connections.setdefault(city1, []).append(city2)
        sorted_connections.setdefault(city2, []).append(city1)
    print(all_possiblities())
```

Input:

```
10 12 4 6
0 1
1 2
2 7
7 6
6 9
9 8
8 4
4 3
3 0
5 1
5 4
5 6
2 0 2
2 8 9
```

Output:

```
8
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input?

Comment: I updated my question with example

Comment: @Joe: Is this a programming challenge? If so, can you link to the original problem description?

Answer (score 5):

The key reasons for the poor performance are:

1. Representing `queue` as a list. This is slow because popping an item off the beginning of a list [takes time proportional to the length of the list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

   What you need here is a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).
2. Computing shortest distances many times over. The shortest distance from `a` to `clinique` is computed again for every `clinique2`, even though it will be the same each time. Similarly, the shortest distance from `clinique2` to `b` is computed again for every `clinique`.

   What you need here is to compute these distances once and remember them.

   If the number of cliniques is large compared with the number of cities, you should use the [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to compute distances between all pairs of cities in one go (instead of using Dijkstra's algorithm many times, as in the posted code).

If I were implementing this, I'd use [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall.html) and write:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import floyd_warshall

def shortest_distance_via(graph, a, b, c1, c2):
    """Return the shortest distance in graph from a to b via C1 and C2 (in
    that order), where C1 and C2 are nodes in c1 and c2 respectively.

    Arguments:
    graph -- NxN array of distances between nodes.
    a, b -- nodes in the graph.
    c1, c2 -- arrays of nodes in the graph.

    """
    d = floyd_warshall(graph)
    ab = d[a, c1, np.newaxis] + d[np.meshgrid(c1, c2)] + d[np.newaxis, c2, b]
    return ab.min()
```

Comment: how can i avoid counting the shortest path many times in my code?

Comment: using breath first search?

Comment: @Joe: Compute each path once and remember it!